# Why is there no Intellisense with 'var' variables in 'foreach' statements in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Forgive me if this is a duplicate, but it's a minor issue for me and I can only spend so long on my curiosity.  Why is it that when I use an implicitly typed loop variable in a foreach block, I get no Intellisense?  The inferred type seems to be quite obvious.

I am using ReSharper, but when I switch the Intellisense to VS I get the same behaviour, and this don't think it's to blame.

EDIT:  Sorry, a bit later, but I was iterating DataTable.Rows, which uses an untyped ieterator, as Marc explains below.

Comment: Post the code, it normally works for me.

Comment: Using VS, it works on my machine ... how is this a programming question anyway?

Comment: My suspicion is that the collection is of type Object, that would give the least amount of Intellisense... Apart from that, var always works for me in a foreach

Comment: Never had that problem using Resharper or VS. What version of Resharper? What version of VS? What's the container? (Is it IEnumerable or IEnumerable<T>)?

Comment: try restarting vs, works for me too

Comment: @Joren, it is directly related to my use of my primary programming tool, and I suspect that of many others here.

Comment: @Ian, it is IEnumerable, whose enumerator returns objects, not more specific types.  Shame on MS for not genericising System.Data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that the data you are enumerating is not typed - for example, a **lot** of things that were written in 1.1 only implement `IEnumerable`, and don't have a custom iterator (you don't actually need `IEnumerable<T>` to do typed iteration - and indeed you don't even need `IEnumerable` to use `foreach`; a lot of 1.1 typed wrote special enumerator types to avoid boxing/casting etc - lots of work). In many cases it would be a breaking change to fix them.

A trivial example here is `PropertyDescriptorCollection`:

```
var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj);
foreach(PropertyDescriptor prop in props) {...} // fine
```

but actually, `PropertDescriptorCollection`'s enumerator is just `IEnumerator`, so `Current` is `object` - and hence you'll always get `object` when you use `var`:

```
var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj);
foreach(var prop in props) {...} // prop is "object"
```

Contrast this to the (equally 1.1) `StringCollection`; this has a custom enumerator (`StringEnumerator`); so if you used `foreach` with `var`, you'd get `string` (not `object`).

In anything 2.0 and above, it would be reasonable to expect better typing, for two reasons:

- generics (for the simple cases), making it possible to write strongly-typed collections sensibly
- iterator blocks (for the non-trivial cases), making it possible to write custom iterators without going insane

But even then there are still cases when you don't get the type you expect; you can either (and perhaps more clearly) specify the type manually, or use `Cast<T>()` / `OfType<T>()`.

Comment: This happens to me a lot.  Cast<T>() works, but I find it clearer to just not use var in this case.

Comment: @Stuart B - indeed; the "specify the type manually" involves less indirection too, so *marginally* quicker as well as clearer.