# Is .NET old code updated in new releases?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm just asking this, because the same happened to me when trying to iterate over a `DataRowCollection`:

```
DataSet s;
...
foreach (var x in s.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    //IntelliSense doesn't work here. It takes 'x' as an object.
}
```

I saw @Marc Gravell answer in [Why is there no Intellisense with 'var' variables in 'foreach' statements in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695894/why-is-there-no-intellisense-with-var-variables-in-foreach-statements-in-c), and now it's clear to me why this is happening.

I decided to take a look at the code of the `DataRowCollection` class, and `GetEnumerator()` is:

```
return this.list.GetEnumerator();
```

where `list` is a `DataRowTree` type that inherits the abstract class `RBTree<K>` (*by the way, never knew there was an implementation of a Red-Black Tree in .NET before*) which implements `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<K>`.

Is too hard to make `RBTree<K>` implement `IEnumerable<K>`? That would solve the main problem here.

I suppose it was developed like this in previous versions of .NET, but that doesn't really make sense anymore, does it?

**My question is:**

**Is .NET old code updated in new releases?** (for example, make `DataRowCollection` implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>` instead of `IEnumerable`)

Comment: Umm, I'm almost positive that there *isn't* an `RBTree<T>` class in the .NET Framework. [I believe Java has one](http://net0.datastructures.net/doc4/net/datastructures/RBTree.html), but it isn't in the BCL. Where are you getting that from?

Comment: @Cody It's *internal*, and is under `System.Data` namespace. Reflector will tell you this. First I was in doubt about this, but it also has a *enum* `NodeColor`. Am I wrong?

Comment: **Downvoter**: Could you leave a comment, please?

Comment: I see. I didn't realize we were talking about internal classes that aren't *exposed* by the framework. These classes are declared internal for a reason; you're not supposed to rely on the functionality that they contain. I'm not really sure what the question is here. (Not my downvote, in case you're wondering.)

Comment: @Cody I edited my question (and don't worry, never thought about you, and in case you would, you did leave a comment ;)

Comment: code that uses RBTree<DataRow> [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/DataRowCollection.cs#efb888e10249a7ca#references).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Breaking changes, such as changing the class hierachy, is only implemented if there's a really good reason. In this case it's only for convinience.

An example of why it's a breaking change:
Let's say a project has these two methods.

```
public void Foo(object obj){
   Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString();
}

public void Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> obj){
  throw new Exception();
}
```

now the change you want will make a program that has been recompiled but not changed throw an exception every time instead of printing to the console. It's not that it throws that's the problem but that the behaviour is different.

There's other ways such a change could break/alter a perfectly good program so the benefits (being able to write var in foreach loops) does not outweigh the cost (designing, implementing,testing,documenting), nor the potential costs of breaking customers work.